# Delete rows in dataframe with a dot in its rowname, keep the rest

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called "missingdata" and some of its rownames are duplicate such as "Austria", "Austria.1" and "Austria.2".

I want to delete those rows entirely, which have a dot in its name.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520840/using-regexp-to-select-rows-in-r-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` and `invert = TRUE`

```
missingdata[grep("Austria\\.\\d+$", row.names(missingdata), invert = TRUE),]
```

Or if it is not specific to a particular prefix

```
missingdata[grep("\\.\\d$$", row.names(missingdata), invert = TRUE),]
```